# How to use the data from MapStatetoProps function to components

Tags: react-native, react-redux

I want to be able to use the data I got from MapStateToProps function to my components.

MY GOAL:

1. Use the data I got from userData refer to image posted below.
2. Using the mapStatetoProps function I want it to be props that I can call and use to the input components.
3. Im a beginner in react-native and redux also so please bear with me.

[image: this is the data that I get from userData, I want this to appear on the input components]

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Picker, Image, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import {Actions} from 'react-native-router-flux';
import * as actions from '../actions';
import {
  Drawer,
  Container,
  Content,
  Item,
  Input,
  H3,
  Form,
  Label,
  Thumbnail
 } from 'native-base';
import {Button} from 'react-native-elements';
import AppHeader from './AppHeader';
import Sidebar from './Sidebar';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class ProfileScreen extends Component {

  state = { language: 'english' };

  closeDrawer = () => {
    this.drawer._root.close()
  };

  openDrawer = () => {
    this.drawer._root.open()
  };
  render(){

    return (
    <Container>
      <Drawer
        ref={(ref) => { this.drawer = ref; }}
        content={<Sidebar/>}
        onClose={() => this.closeDrawer()}
        side={'right'}>
        <AppHeader
            title='Profle'
            openDrawer={this.openDrawer.bind(this)}
        />
        <Content>
            <H3 style={{ marginTop: 20, marginLeft: 10 }}>Edit Profile</H3>
            <Image
            style={styles.thumbStyle}
            source={require('../assets/thumb.png')}
             />
            <Form style={{marginTop: 10}}>

              <Item floatingLabel>
                <Label>Name</Label>
                <Input />
              </Item>

              <Item floatingLabel>
                <Label>Birthday</Label>
                <Input />
              </Item>

              <Item floatingLabel>
                <Label>Gender</Label>
                <Input />
              </Item>

              <Item floatingLabel>
                <Label>Province</Label>
                <Input />
              </Item>


              <View  last style={{ justifyContent: 'center',alignItems: 'center', marginTop: 40}}>
                <Button
                backgroundColor='#397af8'
                title='Edit'
                buttonStyle={{ width: 200, borderRadius: 5, borderColor: '#397af8'}}

                large
                />
              </View>

            </Form>
        </Content>
      </Drawer>
     </Container>

    );
  }
}
const drawerStyles = {
  drawer: { shadowColor: '#000000', shadowOpacity: 0.8, shadowRadius: 3},
  main: {paddingLeft: 3},
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  thumbStyle: {
    width: 120,
    height: 120,
    alignSelf: 'center'
  }
});

// const mapStateToProps = state => {
//   return { userData: state.userData  };
//   console.log(state.userData);
// };

function mapStateToProps(state, userData) {
  return {

  };
}

 export default connect (mapStateToProps, actions)(ProfileScreen);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is absolutely fine:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return { userData: state.userData  };
};
```

useage inside your view: `this.props.userData`

You can also perform a little bit of destructuring inside your mapStateToProps:

```
const mapStateToProps = ({ userData }) => {
    return { userData };
};
```

It's shorter to write, but the usage does not change.

Answer (score 1):

just use `this.props.userData` in your component

Answer (score 1):

It's correct both:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
   return { userData: state.userData  };
};

const mapStateToProps = ({ userData }) => {
    return { userData };
};
```

But if you want to improve it, it's possible! you can also do this:

```
const mapStateToProps = ({ userData }) => ({
    userData,
});
```